# How to extend express router function?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, routes

Is possible to extend express router function? I need to send soket.io along with response and request.

In one file i have router:

```
var contoller = require('controller');
...
module.exports = function(app, io) {
   router.post('/', controller.postAction);
}
```

Controller file look something like this:

```
...
controler.prototype.postAction = function(req, res) {

}
...
```

So from first file I need to send ´io´ to controller, how can I do that?

Comment: What does `send soket.io along with response and request` mean?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  You can always add middleware that will add a custom property to `req` or `res`.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the actual `postAction` function which itself returns a function and pass `io` to the `postAction` function, like below:

```
controler.prototype.postAction = function(io) {  // you receive io as an argument
    return function(req, res){
       // your midleware code here
    }
}
```

and you can require this in your router like:

```
var contoller = require('controller');
...
module.exports = function(app, io) {
   router.post('/', controller.postAction(io)); // note here we pass io
}
```

What happens here is the function `postAction` acts as a wrapper which returns the actual middleware, so you can easily pass any argument to it.

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for!

Comment: It is good solution, but is possible to set `io` as property inside controller file and use it without passing to function?